# How to interpolate variables into Perl 6 regex character class?

Tags: raku

I want to make all the consonants in a word uppercase:

```perl6
> my $word = 'camelia'
camelia
> $word ~~ s:g/<-[aeiou]>/{$/.uc}/
(｢c｣ ｢m｣ ｢l｣)
> $word
CaMeLia
```

To make the code more general, I store the list of all the consonants in a string variable

```perl6
my $vowels = 'aeiou';
```

or in an array

```perl6
my @vowels = $vowels.comb;
```

How to solve the original problem with `$vowels` or `@vowels` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [moritz's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47260479/7730888), here is the solution:

```perl6
my constant $vowels = 'aeiou';
my regex consonants {
    <{
       "<-[$vowels]>"
     }>
}

my $word = 'camelia';
$word ~~ s:g/<consonants>/{$/.uc}/;
say $word;  # CaMeLia
```

Comment: This can also be done inline as well: `/<{"<-[$vowels]>"}>/` [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3UiE5P6@4JDGvREGlLL88NadYwVZBPTE1M79U3ZqLCyivUp5flAISTE7MTc3JTAQKQ4Tq6hSKrdL1baqVbHSjoZpj7ZRq7fSrVfT1SpNr9a25ihOhBlj//w8A "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the `trans` method would be more appropriate than the `subst` sub or operator.

Try this:

```
my $word = "camelia";
my @consonants = keys ("a".."z") (-) <a e i o u>;
say $word.trans(@consonants => @consonants>>.uc);
# => CaMeLia
```

Comment: Thanks! It's indeed much easier in this case. Do I understand correctly that `(-)` coerces the two lists to sets and `keys` makes the result of set subtraction a list?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what happens. could have done it any number of ways, but this one was the simplest i could come up with :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<!before …>` along with `<{…}>`, and `.` to actually capture the character.

```perl6
my $word = 'camelia';
$word ~~ s:g/

  <!before         # negated lookahead
    <{             # use result as Regex code
      $vowel.comb  # the vowels as individual characters
    }>
  >

  .                # any character (that doesn't match the lookahead)

/{$/.uc}/;
say $word;         # CaMeLia
```

You can do away with the `<{…}>` with `@vowels`

I think it is also important to realize you can use `.subst`

```perl6
my $word = 'camelia';
say $word.subst( :g, /<!before @vowels>./, *.uc ); # CaMeLia
say $word;                                         # camelia
```

---

I would recommend storing the regex in a variable instead.

```perl6
my $word = 'camelia'
my $vowel-regex = /<-[aeiou]>/;

say $word.subst( :g, $vowel-regex, *.uc ); # CaMeLia

$word ~~ s:g/<$vowel-regex>/{$/.uc}/;
say $word                                  # CaMeLia
```

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer! (Though I supposed that the solution would be easier — I wasted a lot of time trying to find it after being stuck in my current program). After reading your answer several times and then testing the code snippets with different changes, I at last understand much better, how lookahead and lookbehind work. As for the last solution, my question remains: how to interpolate `@vowels` or `$vowels` into `$vowel-regex`. In my programs, it would be better not to have such info 'hard-coded'.

Comment: Finally, I've got it! `my $vowel-regex = "/<-[$vowels]>/".EVAL;` Thanks again for your explanations!

Comment: @EugeneBarsky You can do the eval in-line: `my $match-consonant-rx = /<{ "<-[$vowels]>" }>/;`