# Building a regex with sub in Perl 6

Tags: raku

After learning [how to pass `regexes` as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47224387/7730888), I've tried to build my first regex using a `sub`, and I'm stuck once more. Sorry for the complex rules below, I've made my best to simplify them. I need at least some clues how to approach this problem.

The `regex` should consist of alternations, each of them consisting of `left`, `middle` and `right`, where `left` and `right` should come in pairs and the variant of `middle` depends on which `right` is chosen.

An array of `Pairs` contains pairs of `left` and `right`:

```perl6
my Pair @leftright =
  A => 'a',
  ...
  Z => 'z',
  ;
```

`Middle` variants are read from a hash:

```perl6
my Regex %middle = 
  z => / foo /,
  a => / bar /,
  m => / twi /,
  r => / bin /,
  ...
  ;
```

`%middle<z>` should be chosen if `right` is `z`, `%middle<a>` — if `right` is `a`, etc.

So, the resulting regex should be

```perl6
my token word {
    | A <%middle[a]> a
    | Z <%middle[z]> z
    | ...
}
```

or, more generally

```perl6
my token word {
    | <left=@leftright[0].key> 
      <middle=%middle{@leftright[0].value}> 
      <right=@leftright[0].value> 
    | (the same for index == 1)
    | (the same for index == 2)
    | (the same for index == 3)
 ...
}
```

and it should match `Abara` and `Zfooz`.

How to build `token word` (which can be used e.g. in a `grammar`) with a `sub` that will take every pair from `@leftright`, put the suitable `%middle{}` depending on the value of `right` and then combine it all into one `regex`?

```perl6
my Regex sub sub_word(Pair @l_r, Regex %m) {
...
}
my token word {
    <{sub_word(@leftright, %middle)}> 
}
```

After the match I need to know the values of `left`, `middle`, and `right`:

```perl6
"Abara" ~~ &word;
say join '|', $<left>, $<middle>, $<right> # A|bar|a
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying something to the effect that, given a right that's `X`, the middle is `/ waldo /`. But you haven't said what programmatic relationship is supposed to be detected between `X` and `waldo`. (Granted, you wrote `z` not `X` and `/ zfoo /` not `/ waldo /` but that makes no difference, unless you are meaning that the `z` in `/ zfoo /` isn't just to aid human understanding but is also to be detected by the program. In which case, no, I don't think you can do that -- I don't think your program can introspectively know that the `/ zfoo /` pattern contains a `z`.)

Comment: What would be the input parameters to the sub that should build the token `word`? Should the sub be used before the regex parsing starts to build a predefined `token`, or should it be used within the regex parser? Can you give a simple example?

Comment: @raiph Thanks That's my fault (and I thought about it), I didn't mean introspection into a `regex`. I'll reformulate this part, making a `hash`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland The input parameters should be `@leftright` and `%middle`, and the pattern should be built before the parsing begins. If there were only one variant the pattern would be smth like `<$left> <$middle> <$right>`. Here it should be `<@leftright[0].key> <%middle{@leftright[0].value}> <@leftright[0].value> | (the same for index == 1 | then 2, 3 etc)...` So the problem is that I e.g. don't know how to concatenate `regexes` with alternation `|` in a loop.

Comment: I've reworked the text of the question. Hope, now it's better.

Comment: Your solution works with my data, but in future I need to do the same with `Regex middle`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to do this using `token` yet, but here is a solution with `EVAL` and `Regex` (and also I am using `%middle` as a hash of `Str` and not a hash of `Regex`):

```
my Regex sub build_pattern (%middle, @leftrigth) {
    my $str = join '|', @leftright.map(
        {join ' ',"\$<left>='{$_.key}'", "\$<middle>='{%middle{$_.value}}'", "\$<right>='{$_.value}'"});
    );
    my Regex $regex = "rx/$str/".EVAL;

    return $regex;
}

my Regex $pat = build_pattern(%middle, @leftright);

say $pat;
my $res = "Abara" ~~ $pat;
say $res;
```

**Output**:

```
rx/$<left>='A' $<middle>='bar' $<right>='a'|$<left>='Z' $<middle>='foo' $<right>='z'/
｢Abara｣
 left => ｢A｣
 middle => ｢bar｣
 right => ｢a｣
```

For more information on why I chose to use `EVAL`, see [How can I interpolate a variable into a Perl 6 regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40883160/2173773)

Comment: Thanks! Probably, that will be the most effective way, but in my case I need to have the possibility to analyze `$/`. E.g. I need to know which `middle` matched. I'll add this to the Q, sorry I haven't written it beforehand.

Comment: Then maybe put a capture group around the middle part? Like this: my $pat = `rx/'A' ('bar') 'a'|'Z' ('foo') 'z'/`. Then `$0` will contain the middle part after a successful match..

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with a named (not positional) capture? That would be a very nice solution for me.

Comment: So, will the following be correct (modifying your A)? `"<middle='{%middle{$_.value}}'>"`, `"<left='{$_.key}'>"`, "<right='{$_.value}'>"

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Yes that is a good idea! See my updated answer for a suggestion

Comment: That's what I needed to move forward!! Could you please explain the syntax? I mean `\` before `$`, `'..'` around `{}`, and `$<right>=...` instead of `<right=...>`?

Comment: Sure :) I think the syntax I used with `$<right>` is explained here: https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Named_captures What other parts of the syntax did you refer to?

Comment: I wanted to ask escaping `$` and taking `{$_.key}` in `'` quotes. I suppose both mean that these parts of the string are not to be interpolated during `EVAL`?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky We need to escape the `$` because it is inside double quotes, and since we do not want it to be interpolated. I.e., the literal `$` must survive the first `join` call. For the other question: the single quotes are there since we are not using sigspace in the regex, hence all literal strings should be in quotes. If not, we would get a warning when compiling the regex (here that is: when using `EVAL`).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I supposed but wasn't sure. A wonderful technique!

Comment: @HåkonHægland "I was not able to do this using `token` yet" Just add a [`:r`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Ratchet) as the first thing in the regex, then it'll be exactly equivalent to a `token`.